# multiple tokenizer using filebeat

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I have multiple log files and I want to parse the `message` to get the correct timestamp. Here is the issue,
I had logs that were ingested at later date because of which the service count hits are astronomical high around that date. But, since the logs of the file have the correct date and time, I am planning to correct my `@timestamp` using that.

I tried to find the [dissect processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/7.10/dissect.html) and came up with the following code snippet:

```yaml
processors:
  - dissect:
      tokenizer: '[%{text1}] [%{text2}] [%{text3}] [%{text4}] %{text5}'
      field: 'message'
```

1. Since, I have multiple logs I am not sure how to have multiple tokenizers to capture all patterns for the logs.
   Examples:

```
[UUID] [timestamp] [loglevel] [text] msg
```

```
[timestamp] loglevel msg
```

```
loglevel [timestamp] msg
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a hacky way: You can copy the message to multiple fields and have dissect processor for each of those fields with different tokenizer.

The downside/tradeoffs would be:

- you will be copying the raw log multliple times over to different fields, so the actual event size would increase.
- you will need to check multiple fields for your parsed tokens